# With iOS, is it possible to detect when an iPhone is turned on?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

It would be incredibly useful for a project I am working on that if, when the iOS device is turned on and boots up, I can save a timestamp of that occurrence. Is there any code I can run that will store this variable? If not, is there a way I can check without opening the app if an iPhone is on at a certain time?

Thanks!

Sorry for the confusion: 
I want to make an app that has the capability to remember the last time an iOS device was turned on.

Comment: Xcode is just an IDE - presumably you mean that you want to do this in iOS, i.e on the iPhone itself, somehow ?

Comment: I want to make an app that has the capability to remember the last time an iPhone was turned on.

Comment: That information is in the system log, so you just need to find a way to access that. Note that this still has very little to do with Xcode, so I suggest you edit your title to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you for your help an advice. I apologize- I'm still a bit new.

Comment: No problem - you'll probably find that you get lots of helpful comments like this to guide you when you're new. ;-)

Comment: Awesome:) glad I found this place, I've been using it for months but just now got an account. One more question, if you don't mind. If I can access the system log of an iPhone, how far back can I look? Can I look back multiple on/off cycles?  Thanks again!

Comment: I think so - you can check out the iPhone system log from within Xcode when your iPhone is connected to see what information is there.

Comment: actually it is not iPhone but iOS specific.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the `kern.boottime` sysctl, which tells you when the system booted. I don't believe it would throw you out of the app store in this case:

```
#import <sys/sysctl.h>

- (time_t)bootTime
{
    struct timeval boottime;
    int item[2] = { CTL_KERN, KERN_BOOTTIME };
    size_t size = sizeof(boottime);
    int st = sysctl(item, 2, &boottime, &size, 0, 0);
    if (st < 0)
        return -1;
    return boottime.tv_sec;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No this is not possibe in iOS.